# DNS leak over Wireguard due to NetworkManager

Tags: dns, networkmanager, wireguard

I recently setup a VPS to run PiHole and Wireguard. One a system (running Pop OS 22.04 with kernel 6.2.6) connected to the VPS and with the VPS set as the gateway and DNS (it is running a local instance of Unbound that PiHole uses to resolve queries) I get DNS leaks and the gateway of whatever network I am connected to pops up from time to time.

My Wireguard configuration on the peer that is experiencing the leaks; IPs have been changed, but `1.0.0.1` would be my VPSes internal Wireguard address and `1.0.0.4` would be for this particular peer connected to the VPS:

```bash
[Interface]
PrivateKey = 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111
Address = 1.0.0.4
DNS = 1.0.0.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = 2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
PresharedKey = 333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = vps.running.wireguard:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

The VPS is setup to answer to queries only on the Wireguard interface. PiHole has no other DNS configured apart from the Unbound instance that runs on it. Unbound has been configured in line with the PiHole documentation with only changes made to the IP ranges that I use.

My local *resolv.conf* file has only this:

```bash
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 1.0.0.1
```

I have looked around through the Arch wiki and found that `rc-manager=unmanaged` should disable NetworkManager from updating *resolv.conf*, however, I think that's not always true as NetworkManager could still `symlink` *resolv.conf* to its own local state, thus overwritting the nameserver found here.

The only way that I found to be reliable to stop DNS leaks was to manually set a DNS record to `1.0.0.1` inside NetworkManager. This however, works only on a connection by connection basis and not as a full rule as I add these inside the */etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/[connectionName].nmconnection* file. This means that each new connection could overwrite this behavior.

Not only that, but forcing the DNS to be that specific address means that when changing connections I might find myself without an Internet connection and have to revert the setting to allow a default DNS server to be picked up.

Is there some other way this can be enforced across connections, some setting I'm missing or some other configuration that I failed to see or understand correctly? This is on a fresh install btw and I have noticed it on a fresh install of Debian Buster too.

Comment: is this what you're looking for?: https://andrea.corbellini.name/2020/04/28/ubuntu-global-dns/

Comment: First off, really enjoy your site and the product; I'll test it out and come back if it works. I think the section in which a new conf is provided for Networkmanager should solve the first part of the issue, which is that NetworkManager overwrites the DNS record. I'm curious to see how it handles connection switching, as in, moving from one network to another as having the DNS set to the Wireguard one will mean that until the tunnel is created, the device cannot resolve DNS records. I guess I'm conflating several things here.